# Difference in declaring IDisposable member in using block or at using block declaration?

Tags: c#, dispose, using-statement

I have the code below:

```
    using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
    {

        command.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        command.Connection = new SqlConnection();
        command.CommandText = "";

        command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@ExperienceLevel", 3).Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Input);

        SqlDataReader dataReader = command.ExecuteReader();
   }
```

Is there any functional impact in declaring the SqlConnection where I currently am declaring it as opposed to like so?:

```
using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand())
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection())
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there's a difference.  Disposing the `SqlCommand` does not automatically dispose the `SqlConnection` it's associated with.  You can leak connections that way, and it will interfere with ADO.NET connection pooling; if you take a look at the database server's activity while this code runs, you'll see new connections being opened and not closed.

You should always be using the second version.  In fact, the `SqlConnection` object is the one that you really *need* to `Dispose`.  You should always dispose *anything* that implements `IDisposable` as soon as possible, but failing to dispose a `SqlConnection` is particularly dangerous.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, preferably use 2 using blocks, 1 per resource.

In this case you could use just 1 but it should be around the Connection, not around the Command.

But you really don't want to know or care about such details. If a class implements the IDispsoable interface then use its instances in a `using() { }` block unless there is a special reason not to.

Answer (score 2):

I use the following pattern:

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection("ConnectionName"))
using(var command = new SqlCommand())
{
   command.Connection = connection;
   // setup command
   var reader = command.ExecuteReader();
   // read from the reader
   reader.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the below code will dispose the SqlConnection correctly, the above won't.  A `using` block (implemented internally as `try`...`finally`) ensures that the object will be disposed no matter how you exit the block.